# async.auto: stop entire chain after first error

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I was under the impression that the behavior of `async.auto` was that if one of the tasks returned an `err`, the global callback would be called with this error and **all** subsequent tasks would not execute. After all, why would they? The global callback has been called so the error has been reported already.

It turns out that only tasks *that depend on the faulty task* will not run, and the rest will.

```
'use strict';

var async = require('async');

async.auto({
    downloadAudio: function (callback) {
        console.log("downloading audio...");
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("downloaded audio.");
            callback();
        }, 10000);
    },
    downloadScript: function (callback) {
        console.log("downloading script...");
        setTimeout(function () {
            return callback(new Error("ERROR downloading script!"));
        }, 1000);
    },
    preprocessAudio: ['downloadAudio', function (callback) {
        console.log("preprocessing audio...");
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("done preprocessing audio.");
            callback();
        }, 5000);
    }]
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
    }

    console.log('done.');
});
```

In this code snippet, both `downloadAudio` and `downloadScript` will immediately run in parallel, and `preprocessAudio` depends on `downloadAudio`. The problem is that when `downloadScript` returns an `err`, `preprocessAudio` will still run, even though there's no point because the thing failed as a whole already:

```
downloading audio...
downloading script...
ERROR downloading script!
downloaded audio.
preprocessing audio...
done preprocessing audio.
```

I know, I could make `preprocessAudio` depend on `downloadScript` also but that means that `preprocessAudio` would wait for `downloadScript` to complete, even though they could run in parallel without a problem.

Is there any elegant way to solve this?

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: This issue has been marked as a bug in the meanwhile: https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/1023

Answer (score 0):

Given then that you don't want preprocessaudio to run if downloadScript has returned an error, preprocessaudio really does 'rely' on the other two functions.

Just add the dependency and all should work correctly.

```
'use strict';

var async = require('async');

async.auto({
    downloadAudio: function (callback) {
        console.log("downloading audio...");
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("downloaded audio.");
            callback();
        }, 10000);
    },
    downloadScript: function (callback) {
        console.log("downloading script...");
        setTimeout(function () {
            return callback(new Error("ERROR downloading script!"));
        }, 1000);
    },
    preprocessAudio: ['downloadAudio', 'downloadScript', function (callback) {
        console.log("preprocessing audio...");
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("done preprocessing audio.");
            callback();
        }, 5000);
    }]
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
    }

    console.log('done.');
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work because `function (err, callback)` is not the proper signature; it's either `function (callback)` or `function (callback, results)`. You'll notice `preprocessAudio` won't run even if `downloadScript` *does* succeed. I haven't looked into promise chaining; I figured the async library is able to do the heavy lifting for me.

Comment: Yeah I just confirmed that callback isn't valid. However, I'm a little confused now as to what it is you're trying to achieve. You don't want preprocessAudio to run if downloadScript fails, but you don't want preprocessAudio to wait for downloadScript and you don't want preprocessAudio to be dependent on downloadScript, when it obviously is if you want everything to exit if downloadScript fails? Doesn't make a lot of sense to try to make processAudio not run if downloadScript fails, but then not wait to see if it is successful :/

Comment: I think a comibination of async parallel and async series/auto might better address this, but I don't see how it's possible to have preprocessAudio run only if downloadScript is successful but not wait for it to complete.

Comment: I'm just not sure if it makes sense for `async.auto` to report failure by means of a single global callback on one hand, and still run further tasks on the other hand: as far as the client is concerned, the whole thing already failed. I mean, what's the point in running them if `async.auto` is never going to be able to notify the client of their outcome?

Comment: You're basing your opinion of async.auto on a single use case. Just because one task failed, doesn't mean "the whole thing already failed" for every use case. For your scenario, yes, but for many, many others, no. There are many use cases where you may want several tasks to run, knowing that they might fail, but you still need the others that are not bound by dependency to complete.

Comment: Anyway - I think you've made your use case overcomplicated. Setting downloadAudio and downloadScript as a dependency of preprocessAudio means they will run in parallel and then only execute preprocessAudio if all is well. You can't have preprocessAudio only run if downloadScript is successful, but not wait for downloadScript to complete. Makes no sense.